# How can I make groups of 5 for the same ID with different values in another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table called XIPNMVSCHECK that has lots of columns, the 2 main ones being CODBULTO which identifies a box and the other one NUMEROSERIE which identifies de serial number of a product. I want a query that returns for each line the CODBULTO and 5 columns called SSCC1 to SSCC5 that contain serial numbers of that particular box. So, for example I have CODBULTO: 35 and this box has 10 serial numbers, I would like to get the following result:

```
CODBULTO  SSCC1  SSCC2  SSCC3  SSCC4  SSCC5
   35      265    652    452    656    125
   35      145    489    978    842    546
```

A CODBULTO can have a lot more serial numbers, 10 is just an example.
I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT T1.CODBULTO,
MAX(CASE WHEN T1.POS = 1 THEN T1.NUMEROSERIE END) AS SSCC1,
MAX(CASE WHEN T1.POS = 2 THEN T1.NUMEROSERIE END) AS SSCC2,
MAX(CASE WHEN T1.POS = 3 THEN T1.NUMEROSERIE END) AS SSCC3,
MAX(CASE WHEN T1.POS = 4 THEN T1.NUMEROSERIE END) AS SSCC4,
MAX(CASE WHEN T1.POS = 5 THEN T1.NUMEROSERIE END) AS SSCC5
FROM (SELECT X.CODBULTO,
        X.NUMEROSERIE,
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT X2.NUMEROSERIE)
         FROM XIPNMVSCHECK X2
         WHERE X2.CODBULTO = X.CODBULTO
           AND X2.NUMEROSERIE <= X.NUMEROSERIE) AS POS
    FROM XIPNMVSCHECK X) T1
GROUP BY T1.CODBULTO, FLOOR((POS - 1) / 5)
ORDER BY T1.CODBULTO, FLOOR((POS - 1) / 5);
```

But this code only groups the first 5 serial numbers giving me the following result:

```
CODBULTO  SSCC1  SSCC2  SSCC3  SSCC4  SSCC5
   35      265    652    452    656    125
   35      NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
```

If I have more than 5 serial numbers then the next rows will come with the SSCC columns set to NULL. I'm using an old version of Oracle10g, but if the answer is only possible in newer versions I could make it work too. I'd be glad if someone could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide any sample data in its original form, so I guessed as to what it looked like.

Basically, what you need to do is assign a row number to the rows within the box, and then you can use `MOD()` and `CEIL()` to work out the column and row number for each value. Then it's a matter of doing the pivoting.

E.g., you could do it like:

```
WITH   your_table AS (SELECT 35 codbulto, 265 numeroserie FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 35 codbulto, 652 numeroserie FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 35 codbulto, 452 numeroserie FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 35 codbulto, 656 numeroserie FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 35 codbulto, 125 numeroserie FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 35 codbulto, 145 numeroserie FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 35 codbulto, 489 numeroserie FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 35 codbulto, 978 numeroserie FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 35 codbulto, 842 numeroserie FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 35 codbulto, 546 numeroserie FROM dual),
  interim_results AS (SELECT codbulto,
                             numeroserie,
                             mod(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY codbulto ORDER BY numeroserie) -1, 5) + 1 col_num,
                             CEIL(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY codbulto ORDER BY numeroserie)/5) row_num
                      FROM   your_table)
SELECT codbulto,
       MAX(CASE WHEN col_num = 1 THEN numeroserie END) sscc1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN col_num = 2 THEN numeroserie END) sscc2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN col_num = 3 THEN numeroserie END) sscc3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN col_num = 4 THEN numeroserie END) sscc4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN col_num = 5 THEN numeroserie END) sscc5
FROM   interim_results
GROUP BY codbulto,
         row_num
ORDER BY codbulto,
         row_num;

  CODBULTO      SSCC1      SSCC2      SSCC3      SSCC4      SSCC5
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        35        125        145        265        452        489
        35        546        652        656        842        978
```

N.B. I don't know why your output had the numbers in a seemingly random order - when I ran your query against the `your_table` subquery, the results were in numeric order.

If you need the results to come in a different order, you'd need to adjust the `ORDER BY` clause in the row_number analytic functions accordingly.

Comment: Any reason behind using `col_num` column in inner query.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai yes; the col_num column is used to drive which column that value will appear in the final output, as you can see in the conditional `MAX()` aggregate functions in the outer query. The issue with the OP's original query is that they didn't restrict the column position to the max number of columns they wanted to output - the second row is blank because the second row values have column positions of 6 to 10, which haven't been selected.